# Finding and plotting a line tangent to a function

Tags: plotting

Find the equation of the tangent line for the following function. Then plot the original equation and the
tangent line on the same graph.

=cos()         =3 +2         (0,9/8)

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Are you required to use Wolfram Language to solve it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post your formulas in Mathematica code, not the LaTeX.

Comment: Lots of similar questions.  Search here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=plotting+tangent+line